# $http.get JSON from PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, apache

First of all I am new in programming and I am not a native English speaker, so please forgive me any mistakes in correct naming things etc. in the following question :)

This is my JSON output:

```
[{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"1"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"2"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"3"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"4"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"5"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"6"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"7"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"8"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"9"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"10"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"11"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"12"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"13"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"14"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"15"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"16"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"17"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"18"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"19"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"20"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"21"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"22"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"23"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"24"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"25"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"26"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"27"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"28"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"29"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"30"},{"Year":"2017","Month":"1","Day":"31"}]
```

I have checked it on valiator and it was accepted.

This is a RESTful API, using SlimApp, Apache virtual host, mysql database.

This is a

`calendar.php`, which gets the JSON content from the SQL table:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    // echo 'CALENDAR'; });

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM days";

    try {
    // Get DB Object
    $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
    //Connect
    $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

    $stmt = $dbcalendar->query($sql);
    $dbcalendar = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $dbcalendar = null;

    echo json_encode($dbcalendar);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});`.
```

Here are the files from AngularJS:

**days.js**

```
app.factory('days', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('http://slimapp/api/calendar/index.html')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);`,
```

**DaysController.js**

```
app.controller('DaysController', ['$scope', 'days', function($scope, days) {
    days.success(function(data) {
        $scope.days = data;
    });
}]);,
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('CalendarApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            controller: "DaysController",
            templateUrl: "views/test.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirecTo: "/"
        });
});
```

**test.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days"> 
<p> {{day.Year}} </p>
</div>.
```

When I type in http://slimapp/api/calendar in the browser, the JSON content is displayed as shown above.

When put some other code into `test.html`, for example: `<p> Hello world </p>`, everything is displayed fine in the browser.

I use older version of AngularJS1.X, as this is the version I learned on CodeCademy. Therefore I use `.success` and `.error`inside my `$http.get` service.

I have also installed "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin *" extension in my Chrome browser.

When I want to display the JSON content with `test.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days"> 
    <p> {{day.Year}} </p>
</div>
```

I get the blank page in the browser. There isn't any error message, nothing.

Please help my, as I have been struggling with this issue for two days, reading lots of different explainations, comments and so. I really got stuck :(

OK. I have changed `calendar.php` according to suggestion from the comment:

```
`<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    // echo 'CALENDAR'; });

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM days";

    try {
    // Get DB Object
    $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
    //Connect
    $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

    $stmt = $dbcalendar->query($sql);
    $dbcalendar = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $dbcalendar = null;

    echo json_encode($dbcalendar);
    header("Content-type:application/json");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});`
```

but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried returning the [JSON response from SLIM](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html)?  Barring that your db query is successful this should work:

```
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    // echo 'CALENDAR'; });

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM days";

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
        //Connect
        $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

        $stmt = $dbcalendar->query($sql);
        $dbcalendar = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        // $dbcalendar = null;

        return $response->withJson($dbcalendar);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = array('error' => array('text' => $e->getMessage()));
        return $response->withJson($error,500);
    }

});
```

Comment: There is still blank page on Chrome. On Internet Explorer 11 the browser is asking whether to open/save `calendar.json` file. When I try to open it, the result is similar to the one on Chrome. _However I saved the file on my hard drive and changed the path inside the `$http.get` service_ **and it worked.** Please advise what else should be changed, **so I can get the same result by typing the localhost root in the browser,** as I stated previously in the question. Just one more step left :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content-Type to `application/json` when echoing JSON. This way JavaScript will automatically parse the response string as JSON, otherwise you will have to do so by converting the response by hand with `JSON.parse()`

Your PHP code is also error prone, if an exception is thrown that is not `PDOException` or does not inherit from it, then you will get no information about the error.

Comment: I use Content-Type to application/json in RestEasy Chrome, when echoing JSON. How should the correct PHP look like?

Comment: Before you echo set the "Content-Type" header to "application/json" with http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php